# Window drag event c#

Tags: c#, windows, event-handling, pinvoke

I am trying to hook into the window drag event of every active/visible windows using C# in a System tray app. I have the code to find and move all the windows figured out using PInvoke, but am unable to figure out how to hook into the drag event.

My goal is to run the program in the background and while dragging a window be able to snap it into preset locations (showing preview windows while the drag is occurring and snapping when released).

How would I hook into the window drag event?

Comment: You need to pinvoke SetWinEventHook() and monitor the EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND event.  The odds that this will come to a good end, either in code or because the user actually likes the feature, are not very good.

Comment: Why the negative outlook? There are a number of applications that perform behavior very similar to what I am attempting to create such as WinSplit which I really enjoy. Is there an alternative implementation that you suggest?

Answer (score -1):

You could try to set a [CBT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) hook and handling the case when a window is about to be moved or sized, though this hook monitors much more than just this case:

```
class YourClassName
{
    const int WH_CBT = 5;

    private delegate IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private IntPtr hHook;
    private HookCallback hookCallback = new HookCallback(Callback);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookCallback lpfn, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    public void SetHook()
    {
        using (Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
        {
            using (var mainMod = p.MainModule)
            {
                hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, hookCallback, GetModuleHandle(mainMod.ModuleName, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Unhook()
    {
        return UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    }

    public IntPtr Callback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam
    {
        if (nCode < 0)
            return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

        switch (nCode)
        {
             case 0:
                  // Handle window move/size here
                  // wParam is the handle of the window being moved or sized

             // other cases...
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call `Unhook()` before terminating to free system resources.
For more information on SetWindowsHookEx see the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page.